# Can word2vec algorithm be distributed on multi-computers using tensorflow?

Tags: python, algorithm, tensorflow, distributed-computing, bigdata

I want to train word2vec model on a very big corpus such that embedded words cannot be allocated to RAM.

I know there are existing solutions for the algorithm parallelization, for example [Spark implementation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#word2vec), but I would like to use tensorflow library.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in tensorflow out-of-the-box. The trick is to use variable partitioning, e.g. [`tf.fixed_size_partitioner`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/fixed_size_partitioner), and parameter server replication via [`tf.train.replica_device_setter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/replica_device_setter) to split the variable across several machines. Here's how it looks like in code:

```py
with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(ps_tasks=3)):
  embedding = tf.get_variable("embedding", [1000000000, 20],
                              partitioner=tf.fixed_size_partitioner(3))
```

The best part is that these changes are very local and for the rest of the training code it doesn't make any difference. In runtime, however, these is a big difference, namely `embedding` will be chunked into 3 shards, each pinned to a different `ps` task, which you can run on a separate machine. See also [this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43288147/712995).

Answer (score 1):

The authors of `word2vec` implemented the algorithm using an asynchronous SGD called: `HogWild!`. So you might want to look for tensor flow implementation of this algorithm.

In `HogWild!`, each thread takes a sample at a time and performs an update to the weights without any synchronization with other threads. These updates from different threads can potentially overwrite each other, leading to data race conditions. But `Hogwild!` authors show that it works well for very sparse data sets, where many samples are actually near independent since they write to mostly different indices of the model.